# Perl count repeated strings in array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array that is like

```
my @array = ('cookies','balls','cookies','balls','balls');
```

but the real one is much bigger/longer.

How do I output the count of each repeated string in the array?

like in the example, cookies is 2 and balls is 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"How do I output the count of each repeated string in the array?"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ('cookies','balls','cookies','balls','balls', 'orphan');

my %count;
$count{$_}++ foreach @array;

#removing the lonely strings
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%count)) {
    if ($value == 1) {
        delete($count{$key});
    }
}

#output the counts
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%count)) {
    print "$key:$value\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
cookies:2
balls:3
```

Mind, that 'orphan' wasn't output.

Comment: is there a way to print in the format `cookies:2 /n balls:3`?

Comment: @user2285115 sure, will do it now

Comment: what do you mean by 'orphan'?

Comment: @user2285115 "what do you mean by 'orphan'?" - you said, that only repeated strings should be counted. So I decided to create a non-repeated string in array to make sure, that the algorithm works correctly.

Comment: oh I get it now. I didn't noticed the 'orphan' in the array. You mean if the string isn't repeated, it won't in the output right?

Comment: @user2285115 "you mean if the string isn't repeated, it won't in the output right?" - yes

Comment: Please don't encourage people to use `map` in void context. Use `foreach` instead - `$count{$_}++ foreach @array`.

Comment: @DaveCross Well, I used it first, but then walker suggested map, and it was highly upvoted. I tested it, got no warnings and used it instead. Do you think, it's better to rollback to my original solution?

Comment: @DaveCross ok, I did a rollback

Comment: @user4035 (weird names people have in your country!): No that's not what I meant at all. I meant use the code in my comment. The `map` solution works fine (as you've seen) but it isn't as readable as the `foreach` version (and on older versions of Perl it's less efficient).

Comment: @DaveCross Yes, I read about map generating a list even if it's not saved to a variable. Ok, your foreach is better, then mine, I'll use it instead. Do you know, why Perl doesn't generate a warning, when you refer to an undefined hash element, like `$count{$_}++` for the 1-st time - php makes a notice. That's why I defined the hash for the 1-st time.

Comment: "Do you know, why Perl doesn't generate a warning, when you refer to an undefined hash element" - yes, it's called 'autovivification' and it's one of Perl's best features.

Answer (score 7):

I think we can use

```
map {$count{$_}++;} @array;
```

instead of

```
foreach(@array)
{
    unless(defined($count{$_}))
    {
        $count{$_} = 1;
    }
    else {
        $count{$_}++;
    }
}
```

to simplify the code.

Comment: Using `map` in a void context is a bad idea. I'd write that as `$count{$_}++ foreach @array`.

Comment: You don't have to check if a key is defined before you use the increment operator on it, it will automatically inc undef to 1, without warning. You can just do `$count{$_}++ for @array`.

Answer (score 4):

Using Perl that's a little more idiomatic than some of the other answers...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @array = ('cookies','balls','cookies','balls','balls');

my %count;
$count{$_}++ foreach @array;

say "$_: $count{$_}" foreach grep { $count{$_} != 1 } keys %count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this more shorter code u will not get any thing shorter than this

```
my @array = ('cookies','balls','cookies','balls','balls');
my $hashh = {};
foreach (@array){
       if(exists $hashh->{$_}){
               $hashh->{$_}++;
       } else{
               $hashh->{$_} = 1;
       }
}
print Dumper($hashh);
```

Comment: Removing the `if ... else` would be shorter. If `$hashh->{$_}` doesn't exist, it'll automatically be created when you increment it. `$hashh->{$_}++ for @array;`

Comment: I think that `$hashh->{$_}++ for @array` is quite a lot shorter than your `foreach` loop :-)